# C# Build IF statement based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am going to do my best to ask this question in the least confusing way possible:

I am performing a search against Active Directory using the DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.  I am able to manually build the search criteria when I want different results in the DataGrid that I am placing the data in.  For instance:

```
if (up != null && up.SmartcardLogonRequired == true 
               && up.Custom_Attribute_1.Contains("SomeText"))
{
      // Add items to DataGrid
}
```

And that ALL works just fine.  What I want to do is to be able to build the IF statement by adding checkboxes into my program.  Meaning, the if statement would look like this:

```
if (up != null)
```

Unless the Smartcard Required Checkbox is checked, and then it would look like this:

```
if (up != null && up.SmartcardLogonRequired == true)
```

But if it isn't checked, and the CustomAttribute1 box is, it would look like this:

```
if (up != null && up.Custom_Attribute_11.Contains("SomeText")
```

So basically I'm looking for a conditional IF statement that is built depending on the checkboxes I place in my program.  Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you could get a collection of all your "checkbox"s and put the in a list and iterate over the list checking logic against each checkbox until you want it to stop.

Comment: sounds like you should be using a switch case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a collection of `Func<bool>`. Something like this

```
var conditions = new List<Func<bool>>();

// Append conditions here as much as you want
conditions.Add(() => up != null);

if (SmartcardLogonRequired)
    conditions.Add(() => up.SmartcardLogonRequired == true);

if (someCondition)
    conditions.Add(() => up.Custom_Attribute_11.Contains("SomeText"));

// Evaulate
if (conditions.All(x => x())) {
   // Add items to DataGrid
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/CEr6/0)

Comment: Ok - and how would I add the conditions based on the checkbox result?

Comment: @user3050992 you can wrap each individual Add operation within `if` block. See edit

Comment: Ok - I tried it and am getting System.Object.DisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

Comment: sorry, that error is fixed, however, now when I run it the proper results aren't showing.  If I run it with just one condition up != null, I get 5, one of which has smartcard required.  When I add smartcard required, I get 0 results.

Comment: @user3050992 More info is needed to debug.

Comment: The debug error is fixed - that was my misplaced dispose()....but when adding additional conditions the results are not correct.  It is running, but not returning the correct results.  I added 3 conditions ( != null, surname and givenname) of myself, and did not show up.  When I removed GivenName, I showed up.  But when I run all three by manually placing them in the IF statement, I show up.  Is there a way to determine what the conditions.all argument looks like?

Comment: Oh - I forgot to mention - all of this takes place in a foreach loop, if that matters.